# Search text in file stored as SQL varbinary column in Azure Database

Tags: database, azure, full-text-search, azure-sql-database

We have a Database in Azure where we're storing files of different types(.docx, .doc, .pdf, .txt, .ppt, .pptx) in a varbinary column. I tried to configure the fulltext search like that:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG DbaAttachments;

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.Attachments(
   Attachment TYPE COLUMN FileExtension LANGUAGE 1033
)
KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.Attachments] ON DbaAttachments

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Attachments
WHERE contains(Attachment,'price');
```

I added a record in the table with `.docx` file that contains the word `"price"` but the Select statement doesn't return anything.

The Attachment column is the varbinary column and FileExtension contains the file extension.

I found some filter packs have to be installed when use MS SQL Server Database but what is the right way to this in Azure Database and is it possible?

Comment: What happens when you add * like this `Attachment,'price*'

Comment: Again no results.

Comment: Ca  you try adding star before and adter price  like `*price*`

Comment: Unfortunately no results :(

Comment: The syntax is correct. `select * from sys.fulltext_document_types` shows that '.pdf' is not in the list of supported types for full-text index search so this might be an explanation. Can you try without any .pdf document and let us know what happens? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried with .docx file, not with .pdf.

Comment: What happens if you remove .pdf files from your index? Since the syntax looks correct, you may try to open a support case with Azure. What service tier of Azure SQL Database are you using?

Comment: It's a basic tier. I haven't done anything special to index .pdf files and there are still no .pdf files in the database but just a few .docx files. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with a standard tier?

Comment: It's the same with the standard tier.

Comment: Did you make the insert to .docx document before you create the index?

Comment: Yes. The files were added before the index creation.